# Would it be better to combine print css with main css or using another CSS file for print would be better?

Tags: css, performance, xhtml, printing

Which way is prefer ed and why to use for print,  another css file with media="print" or @media print {....} in same file?

Comment: Dont forget to hide the menu, ads, footer, and other web centric parts of the page. What I usually do is (CSS) *{display:none;} #content{display:block}. This turns off everything, then turns on your specific content areas.

Answer (score 7):

If you handle a lot of traffic, then a separate file with a separate link would be a better approach...why send that print CSS when so few people will actually need it?

Comment: @Nick, can you elaborate what you mean by a separate link? Do you mean an additional `link` element, or a "Print Version" button?

Comment: I mean an additional `link` element...browsers won't fetch this unless you actually go to print.

Comment: see this link http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201002/css_efficiency_tip_use_a_single_stylesheet_file_for_multiple_media/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on

- how many styles your original file has
- how many styles will be for printing only
- how much you think the two parts will expand
- how much traffic you get (use another page)
- how likely printing is
- ...

Basically, there's a lot of variables.