# Is it better to define css for all @media in one css file?

Tags: css, xhtml, printing, handheld

As this article suggesting

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201002/css_efficiency_tip_use_a_single_stylesheet_file_for_multiple_media/

or different external CSS for different media would be better option?

in terms of maintainability, site performance.

Comment: multiple css files will always lower your site's performance.  Combining them reduces http requests.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - but see nick answer of my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083900/would-it-be-better-to-combine-print-css-with-main-css-or-using-another-css-file-f/2083911#2083911

Comment: What technology are you using? Straight up HTML, PHP, ASP.NET, Other?

Comment: I use ASP.NET and I build a handler that combines all my CSS on the server site (sending a single CSS file and caching it).  I add my CSS to the handler dynamically based on whether or not it's needed by the page request.

Answer (score 0):

**Combined Style Sheet Pros:**

- Optimal/Fast
- Good reduction in size after compression
- and yes fewer http requests

**Combined Style Sheet Cons:**

- Messed up; all different style sheets in one place
- Difficult to maintain
- Less readable

Comment: Optimal/Fast = false.  Sorry but multiple style sheets is not optimal or fast.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: i used the wrong word "multiple" i meant multiple sytle sheets combined into one, see my answer again plz :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you can programmatically add CSS files to your client based on the media (as long as you only send ONE css file in the end), then yes, build multiple CSS files based on the @media.

If you cannot add css programmatically, then I would suggest combining them into a single css file (since you have to send them all to the client regardless), thus reducing the number of http requests by the client.

fewer http requests = faster page loads.

Comment: but then main css will be heavy for media="screen" users which are main users very few people will take print and mobile user percentage is very low also

Answer (score 0):

You could use media-dependent @import rules like so:

```
@import url("print.css") print;
@import url("projection.css") projection, tv;
```

it should work in everything but IE5-7 (as per: http://www.westciv.com/wiki/CSS_Guide:_Media#mediaspecific )
I can't test for IE8 so you might be disappointed there too.

it would result in a very small initial CSS load, then upload just the needed stylesheets based on media.